# Changing authentication key of a sector in MIFARE Classic

Tags: python, authentication, raspberry-pi, rfid, mifare

According to Evan's answer in [this page](https://forums.tessel.io/t/change-auth-code/1091), in order to change the authentication key of a sector we need to overwrite the key in the 4th block (final block) of that sector.

The default key is always 'FF FF FF FF FF FF' which is a six bytes key. Now if I try to change it using the `write` method from the [pi-rc522 library](https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522/blob/master/pirc522/__init__.py), it raises an `Index Error` because each block has to be 16 bytes, but the authentication key is only 6 bytes long.

Where am I going wrong?

The device is RC522 and I am using Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only write whole blocks on MIFARE Classic cards. Consequently, you need to write the complete sector trailer and not just key A (the first 6 bytes).

The complete sector trailer looks like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| KEY A                       | ACCESS BITS  | GP | KEY B                       |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If you want all blocks of the sector to be readable/writable with key A only (i.e. no key B is used), you could used the access bits `FF 07 80`. Thus, if you want to set key A to `11 22 33 44 55 66`, you could use this value for the trailer block:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| KEY A                       | ACCESS BITS  | GP | KEY B                       |
| 11   22   33   44   55   66 | FF   07   80 | 00 | 00   00   00   00   00   00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Finally, be careful with what you write into the sector trailer. The access bits are protected by a redundancy mechanism. If you write invalid access bits into the trailer block, the whole sector is irreversibly blocked.

Comment: By the sector trailing you mean the last block of the sector? For example, if `SelectTag` returns `8` - does that mean that the key information will be stored in the block `7`?

Comment: @jdevelop No, it will be stored in block 11.