# Can't authenticate block with key A after writing the sector trailer

Tags: authentication, permissions, nfc, rfid, mifare

I can't authenticate the sector with "key A" after I write new content to the sector trailer block.

My tag is MIFARE Classic 1K and I use "MF_API.dll".

I do this:

- On a new tag with default config, I authenticate with "key A" and value "FFFFFFFFFFFF", and the result is success.
- Then, I write `AAAAAAAAAAAA078069BBBBBBBBBBBB` to the sector trailer.
- When I then try to authenticate with "key A" and value "AAAAAAAAAAAA", it fails. The same thing happens when I try to authenticate with "key B" and value "BBBBBBBBBBBB".

Where is my mistake?

And my second question:
Is there any free software for writing and reading on MIFARE Classic 1K tags?

Answer (score 0):

The value that you write to the sector trailer seems to miss one byte (the value is only 15 bytes long, but the trailer block is 16 bytes long). See [Changing authentication key of a sector in MIFARE Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40826675/2425802) for the format of the sector trailer block.

Moreover, the access bits (`078069`) that you have in your trailer block don't seem to be valid since this would be

```
C1 = 0x8 and nC1 = 7 (-> check okay)
C2 = 0x9 but nC2 = 0 (-> check not okay, since not(C2) would be 0x6)
C3 = 0x6 but nC3 = 0 (-> check not okay, since not(C3) would be 0x9)
```

As a result, if you managed to write this to the sector trailer, the sector will be permanently blocked (due to the checksum mismatch in the access bits), see [Can I recover a MIFARE Classic card?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45745936/2425802).

Based on the values you used, I would guess that you actually wanted to write this to the sector trailer:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAFF078069BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Note that these permissions mean that you can authenticate to that sector with key A only, Key B is readable with those permissions and, consequently, cannot be used for authentication.

Regarding your second question: I would not recommend any specific software. Also, please be aware that this type of question is off-topic here.